# RTC source control error message - The location referenced by property "com.ibm.team.build.maven.projectLocation" does not exist

Tags: clearcase, rtc

Where is the property com.ibm.team.build.maven.projectLocation set in RTC source control ? When I request a build I receive following error :

```
com.ibm.team.build.internal.engine.InvalidPropertyValueException: The location "/my-project-area/projects/my-project" referenced by property "com.ibm.team.build.maven.projectLocation" does not exist.
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.engine.MavenBuildParticipant.getProjectLocation(MavenBuildParticipant.java:261)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.engine.MavenBuildParticipant.validateProjectLocation(MavenBuildParticipant.java:114)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.engine.MavenBuildParticipant.validateProperties(MavenBuildParticipant.java:100)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.engine.CommandLineBuildParticipant.build(CommandLineBuildParticipant.java:74)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.engine.BuildLoop.invokeBuildParticipants(BuildLoop.java:871)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.engine.BuildLoop$2.run(BuildLoop.java:652)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this property should be defined in the **`build.xml`** associate with the RTC (Jazz or buildForge) build.

Note: [this thread](https://jazz.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=15811) has a similar error, and in that case, it was an ownership issue:

> Working with version 3.0.1, fetch only create the folder but does not fetch any files to the file system.
>   The CRRTC3512E error is correct, the ant file does not exist because files were not fetched.
>
> Solved!
>   The owner of the build workspace was incorrect.